# Flash reports I must put leftbrace before const, but it's a class so I can't nest it

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm not sure what to do with this particular bug in AS3, you see the debugger is asking me to put a left before a call to const but it's within a class, and apparently a class can't be nested. Therefore, I'm not sure how I am supposed to resolve this - here's my code:

```
class AvatarChat extends MovieClip
     const USERVAR_X:String = "x"
     const USERVAR_Y:String = "y"
     const USERVAR_DIR:String = "dir"

     const AVATAR_DIRECTIONS:Array = ["E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW", "N", "NE"]
     const AVATAR_SPEED:int = 100 // Expressed in pixels/sec
    }
     var avatars:Array

     function AvatarChat()
    {
        // Nothing to do
    }
```

And yes, this is for Smartfoxserver2X

Comment: Add `{` after top line. Remove `}` below consts statements.

Comment: After I do that, I get this: 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program.
So it's asking me to nest the class, but classes can't be nested, so it doesn't make sense. :P

Comment: No. It's telling you you need another `}` at the end of the file

Answer (score 5):

> but it's within a class

You are putting the cart before the horse. What is **within** a class and what is not is defined by the class block. The class block is the `{` and `}` after the class declaration and whatever is in between the two.

No, `USERVAR_X` is not *within* the class `AvatarChat`, because it's not in the block of this class.

On top of all that, you have a lonely closing `}` after your `const` declarations. Braces should always come in pairs to open and close a block. It's the lonely `}` that *doesn't make sense*.

Here's an example of how your code could look like:

```
package
{
    public class AvatarChat extends MovieClip
    {
        public static const USERVAR_X:String = "x";
        public static const USERVAR_Y:String = "y";
        public static const USERVAR_DIR:String = "dir";

        public static const AVATAR_DIRECTIONS:Array = ["E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW", "N", "NE"];
        public static const AVATAR_SPEED:int = 100; // Expressed in pixels/sec

        private var avatars:Array;

        public function AvatarChat()
        {
            // Nothing to do
        }
    }
}
```

There's a `package` block that wraps around the `class` block, which in turn wraps around all the members of the class.

A proper and consistent indentation can do wonders to readability.

Comment: If I do that it tells me Package is unexpected. :P

Comment: @Ninjaoninja2 which is not within the scope of this question. StackOverflow is not the "fix all my problems" site. Feel free to ask a new separate question on what might be the problem for that. Except for the missing import statement for `MovieClip`, the code that I provided in my answer compiles just fine.

Comment: Well it doesn't for me, and might I add I was being very nice. There was no need for that comment.

Comment: @Ninjaoninja2 again, don't ask new questions in comments. I'd happily think about why package might be unexpected if you asked about it in a separate question. This one was about why the compiler complained about the leftbrace.